# react useContext, when I remove an element, another element get removed instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I'm coding a simple todo app using hooks,
Its functions are(add task, remove task, edit task)... basic stuff

Everything seems to work okay except for the delete button. when I click delete on any element, the last element gets deleted everytime.

the functions for the operations :

```
const [task,setInput] = useState() #new todo
const [todolist,setList] = useState([]) #the todos 
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false) #editing


# I am able to control the text input through this
function handleInput(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    setInput(e.target.value)
    console.log(e.target.value)
}



function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    setList([...todolist,{text:task,id:uuidv4()}]) # each todo has a unique id
    setInput("")
}



function remove(id){
  setList(todolist.filter(t =>t.id !== id)) # Here is the potential issue

}
```

I am passing all the states and functions to the children components

I have a todoList componant that map each task to a Task component
the mapping works correctly,

the Task component has an onClick function like this:

```
function handleRemove(){
   
    remove(props.task.id)
}
```

On theory the remove handler should remove the task with the specific id, yet it removes another task.

current investigations:

when clicking handleRemove the correct id passes,
todolist state has the correct updated list

I'm gonna start this mini project from scratch, yet it would be helpful if I understood why this happened.

```
Example:

 - This is the first Task     x  
 - This is the second Task    x  
 - This is the third Task     x

state = [{text:'This is the first Task,id:1},
         {text:This is the second Task,id:2},
         {text:This is the third Task,id:3}]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clicking on X belonging to first task will yield

 - This is the first Task     x  
 - This is the second Task    x  

state = [{text:This is the second Task,id:2},
         {text:This is the third Task,id:3}]


---------------------------------------
deleting the first task again will yield

 - This is the first Task     x  


state = [{text:This is the third Task,id:3}]
```

Comment: have you logged that id ? is it correct ?

Comment: @AnhTuan yes it is correct, could it be a problem with rendering?

Comment: Everything looks correct. Can you provide a working codesandbox link for the entire code? 
You can also check if your `todolist` state updates after `remove()` is fired. If you pass the correct `id`, there could be a problem in the state being updated.

Comment: @SiddhantVarma You are absolutely correct, the problem with the Task value not being updated correctly, thank you for checking my code I truly appreciate it

Comment: This is definitely related to using `index` as [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) value. Rather use the `task.id` as key so that React can accurately keep track of changed components to render.